# Google Analytics - customize view as statcounter's “Recent came from”

Tags: google-analytics, statcounter

I recently moved to Analytics and was overwhelmed by the choice. A view I'm missing from Statcounter is the "recent came from", which is a list of recent referral activity and the landing page, as shown here: ( got it from Google images )

[image]

I'm guessing it's possible to replicate the layout with Google Analytics but I don't know how. Can you guys help me or at least point me to a good manual?

(I think I'm close to it by going to *Acquisition > referral > secondary dimension > time*, but there I find a lot of options and none of them looks "right")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're close, but I prefer Query Explorer - https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

You need to add:

a) dimensions: Hour of Day (ga:dateHour), Page (ga:pagePath), Full Referrer (ga:fullReferrer)

b) metrics: e.g. Sessions (ga:sessions) or Session Duration (ga:sessionDuration)

c) filters: ga:medium==referral

You could use also "Minute Index" (ga:nthMinute), but then you need to calculate, because it is *Index for each minute in the specified date range. Index for the first minute of first day (i.e., start-date) in the date range is 0, 1 for the next minute, and so on.*

Helpful: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say "thanks", but thanks @jakub.kowalik for showing me this awesome tool! I solved the minute thing by adding ga:minute and sorting by -ga:dateHour,-ga:minute :)